# Citing own work within a paper and being anonymous

Tags: citations, anonymity

I am reading a paper in which the author cites his paper in a very explicit form. The reformulation of one of his sentence in the paper was in this form:

> I have already made this point in a few papers, within a general
>   framework in (Some Name) (1996) and in a related 
>   framework in (Some Name) (1999).

This paper is submitted to a peer-reviewed journal. With this sentence, the author gives an explicit information about his identity and becomes non-anonymous to referees. By the way, he is a well-known guy in his literature.

Is it an acceptable situation ?

ps. I edited the question in order to avoid a confusion. I am just reading the paper and I wanted to know, by curiosity, how a such situation is considered in academia.

Comment: A quick note - it sounds like you are reading and not reviewing the paper so I'd like to mention that not all review processes are double-blind.  Even when they are, it can sometimes be nearly impossible to have complete author anonymity given the need to have properly cited related work.

Comment: I assume it should be "I am reviewing.... this paper is submitted to a journal with  double-Blind reviewing" but I'd let the OP confirm and edit.

Comment: In retrospect, I am really not sure whether OP is just reading the paper, reviewing it, or reviewing it for a double-blind journal. Somehow, the question sounds like (s)he is just reading it ("published in a peer-reviewed journal"), but I guess I am not understanding the question then.

Comment: I think that OP is reading a published paper, but is pretending to be a reviewer in order to create an answerable question. In other words, this question turns hypothetical towards the end. It's quite unclearly written, though. @xLeitix.

Comment: @TRiG But how would that make sense? The blinding done to disguise the identity of the author is undone upon publication, so why would one expect it to still be there?

Comment: I've edited the question so it reflects the position of a reviewer. Otherwise it just wouldn't make sense.

Comment: Even without explicitly stating this, it is in some cases easy to guess the people behind the paper: simply count the authors in the reference list. Or in some fields there is only a (very) small set of people working on a certain problem. Some research institutes build their own software system, so when they talk about an improvement, etc. 9 out of 10 it is that research group. Finally there is also the writing style and common spelling/grammar mistakes people in a certain region make that partially uncover the identity of the author.

Comment: I have seen this situation in a few papers. It may be that the editor was fine with the authors revealing themselves.

Comment: @Magicsowon Was that the case those times you saw it? Or what did the editor say when you asked?

Answer (score 43):

If this is in the context of **double-blind reviewing**, the correct response to this situation is to alert the handling editor or PC chair to this situation. Different venues are differently strict about double blind reviews, so the response to the situation may vary between "well, we don't care if the authors *wants* to reveal himself" to a reject and resubmit (without the incriminating statement and a new set of reviewers). However, which of those it is is not your decision as a reviewer.

If this is **not** in the context of double-blind reviewing, you are aware of the identity of the authors anyway, and this statement gives you no additional information.

If you are just **reading** the paper (and not reviewing), as implied by the wording of your question, then I don't understand the issue. Published papers generally have publicly visible authors, and it is not clear that the incriminating wording was already visible during review. For instance, in many software engineering venues that nowadays use double-blind reviewing, it is customary to "blank" self-citations and to slightly change the phrasing for the review version to make sure that identities are not, or at least not obviously, revealed. This can then be changed back for the camera-ready version.

Comment: It might even not have been in there, but a reviewer asked why Some Name's work has not been mentioned, as it is relevant and so Some Name added that sentence after review (where it is not relevant any more that they are their own).

Answer (score 3):

To pick up a necroposting, if this was *not* a review situation, this is fully valid.

I typically define a flag if the paper is anonymous or not, and include things like acknowledgements in the non-anonymous version only. If the anonymous wording in the paper sounds strange and I'd know no better, I'd also have two versions of this sentence, one anonymous but clumsy for the peer-review and one non-anonymous and better sounding in case of acceptance.